# spyder (runfile,wdir) error

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

So I'm new to coding, and I just installed Anaconda 4.4.0 for an online class that I'm taking. I'm using Spyder 3.1.4 with Python 3.6.1. Every time I execute a script in Spyder, I get the following error:

```
runfile('/Users/MacobJiller/untitled1.py', wdir='/Users/MacobJiller')
```

I don't understand what is going on here. I've browsed for similar issues, but most say to type(spyder --reset) into the terminal, which doesn't resolve my issue. The script still runs, though. For example:

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
```

will yield my data set, but before it executes I get the error above. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: thats not an error just the progress of the interpreter

Comment: See the corresponding Spyder issue https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2254 .

Answer (score 2):

I do not have the privilege of commenting thus I just write my answer over here... It is not an error. It just indicates that you are running the "untitle1.py" file under the directory of "/Users/MacobJiller".

You are fine.

Comment: To add to this, you can run `dataset` in the console to get a view of the contents of `Data.csv`.